# Removing two columns from csv without removing the column heading

Tags: linux

Been stuck on this for a while, managed to remove two columns completely from it but now I need to remove two columns (3 in total) within the 1 column heading. I've attached a snippit from my csv file.

```
timestamp;CPU;%usr;%nice;%sys;%iowait;%steal;%irq;%soft;%guest;%idle
2014-09-17 10-20-39 UTC;-1;6.53;0.00;4.02;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;89.45
2014-09-17 10-20-41 UTC;-1;0.50;0.00;1.51;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;97.99
2014-09-17 10-20-43 UTC;-1;1.98;0.00;1.98;5.45;0.00;0.50;0.00;0.00;90.10
2014-09-17 10-20-45 UTC;-1;0.50;0.00;1.51;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;97.99
2014-09-17 10-20-47 UTC;-1;0.50;0.00;1.50;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;98.00
2014-09-17 10-20-49 UTC;-1;0.50;0.00;1.01;3.02;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;95.48
```

What I'm wanting to do is remove yyyy-mm-dd and also UTC, leaving just 10-20-39 underneath the timestamp column heading. I've tried removing them but I can't seem to do it without taking out the headings.

Thanks to anyone who can help me with this

Comment: So what's the expected output?

Comment: And also, have you tried programming to solve this problem? Any code? Cuz it would be another story if you want someone to write code for you.

Comment: @starrify I only have code for the old version of the .csv file which had two more columns, I used this command but this removed the first two columns but didn't remove the headings, it also left the UTC part which I wanted rid of. cat cpu.csv | awk '{ $1=""; print $0}' I had other commands such as one which removed the ; when I used awk but all of them left me what I thought was 1 step away from correctly formatting my csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following `sed` command works for you:

```
sed '1!s/^[^ ]\+ //;1!s/ UTC//'
```

Explanations:

- `1!` Do not apply to the first line.
- `s/^[^ ]\+ //` Remove the first group of non-space characters at line beginning (`"2014-09-17 "` in your case).
- `s/ UTC//` Remove the string `" UTC"`.

Assuming the `csv` file is stored as `a.csv`, then

```
sed '1!s/^[^ ]\+ //;1!s/ UTC//' < a.csv
```

prints the results to standard output, and

```
sed '1!s/^[^ ]\+ //;1!s/ UTC//' < a.csv > b.csv
```

saves the result to `b.csv`.

#### EDITED:

Added: sample results:

```
[pengyu@GLaDOS tmp]$ sed '1!s/^[^ ]\+ //;1!s/ UTC//' < a.csv
timestamp;CPU;%usr;%nice;%sys;%iowait;%steal;%irq;%soft;%guest;%idle
10-20-39;-1;6.53;0.00;4.02;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;89.45
10-20-41;-1;0.50;0.00;1.51;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;97.99
10-20-43;-1;1.98;0.00;1.98;5.45;0.00;0.50;0.00;0.00;90.10
10-20-45;-1;0.50;0.00;1.51;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;97.99
10-20-47;-1;0.50;0.00;1.50;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;98.00
10-20-49;-1;0.50;0.00;1.01;3.02;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;95.48
```

Comment: Brilliant answer. Appreciate you going into detail with your response, letting me know what each part of the command does and I also appreciate you adding an example result. Thank you.

Comment: @MOS182 Thanks. And it's a pleasure to help. :)

Answer (score 2):

A perl way:

```
perl -pe 's/^.+? (.+?) .+?;/$1;/ if $.>1' file
```

#### Explanation

The `-pe` means "print each line after applying the script to it". The script itself simply substitutes identifies the 3 first non-whitespace words and replaces them with the 2nd of the three (`$1` since the pattern was captured). This is only run if the current line number (`$.`) is greater than 1.

An awk way

```
awk -F';' '(NR>1){sub(/[^ ]* /,"",$1); sub(/ [^ ]*$/,"",$1)}1;' OFS=";" file
```

Here, we set the input field delimiter to `;` and use `sub()` to remove the 1st and last word from the 1st field.

Comment: Personally I don't like `perl` too much, but +1 for it really works. Also I wish I could +1 again for the `awk` version. XD

Comment: Not using perl but thanks for providing an awk version which works! +1 for you. Never knew you could skip a line using awk. Would you be able to explain what each part does?

Comment: @MOS182 I'm not skipping any lines. The `sub()` command is `sub(foo,bar,where)`, meaning it will replace `foo` with `bar` in `where`. Here, the `where` is the 1st field, `foo` is the 1st set of non-space characters up to the first space (`[^ ]* `) for the first call and the last set of non-space characters (`[^ ]$`) for the second.

Comment: @terdon I thought you skipped the first line because any time I previously used awk it ended up making changes to the heading as well. I appreciate the time you spent explaining it, it'll be useful for me in the future. Thank you!

Comment: @MOS182 ah! Yes, sorry. The skipping is done in the `NR>1`. That means "if the current line number (NR) is greater than one". So, the replacement is only done on lines >1. The other cryptic thing is `1;` which simply causes awk to print the current line. Since that is outside the `(NR>1){}` block, all lines are printed.